# php find sitemap on website

Tags: javascript, php, sitemap

i am creating an script for seo check where script need to check website have sitemap or not...

how can i check some website have sitemap or not with php or javascript..

i have tried with check robot.txt but some time if some website not index sitemap robot.txt.

my question is finished but its still saying describe your problem etc.. what should i write? i dont knwo so i am just putting dammy text on text box hoop its owrkkng my question is finished but its still saying describe your problem etc.. what should i write? i dont knwo so i am just putting dammy text on text box hoop its owrkkng my question is finished but its still saying describe your problem etc.. what should i write? i dont knwo so i am just putting dammy text on text box hoop its owrkkng

Comment: i was not looking script that check file exists or not... i am looking if some one saved sitemap file as "mysitemap.xml" so how script findthat file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

the following script is a simple php Curl that checks if a file exists.

```
$checkForFiles = array('robots.txt','sitemap.xml');

$host = 'http://php.net/';

foreach($checkForFiles as $file){
    $url = $host . $file;

    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec ($ch);

    if(curl_getinfo($ch)['http_code'] != 200){
        echo $file . ' does not exist on ' . $host . '<br>';
    }else{
        echo $file . ' does exist on <a target="_blank" href="'.$host . $file.'">' . $host . $file .'</a>' . '<br>';
    }

    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: @rajeev-vishva what do you want to make? A script that checks if the sitemap.xml has been saved using Another name like "sitemap2.xml" or " mysitemap.xml. ". So you want to guess how the user named his file(sitemap.xml)?